# Fazer chamada do libreoffice pelo navegador

Tags: php, laravel

Necessito fazer a edição de um documento online. Chamar o libreoffice pelo navegador e abrir na máquina do cliente, para que seja feita a edição do documento online. Algo que se assemelha a edição online que existe no alfresco. Necessido implementar isso em um sistema Laravel.

Comment: Você quer fazer um editor de textos que funcione no navegador?

Comment: Não. Quero chamar o editor libreoffice instalado na máquina do cliente a partir do navegador, mas também preciso passar um arquivo pra o usuário fazer a edição. Quando o usuário terminar a edição, ele salva e o arquivo alterado e mandando novamente pro sistema web.